# How can I prove 3 vectors build orthogonal coordinate system?

Tags: terminology, coordinate-systems, orthogonality

I have these 3 vectors. how can I prove that these are built in an orthogonal coordinate system and moreover, determine a normalized base vector??

1 = 1 + 22 − 3

2 = 2 + 23

3 = 51 − 22 + 3

Comment: You should simply type the vectors in the question and not link to some .png file. Also, do you what is means to be an orthogonal basis? Or even a basis? And what normalized means?

Comment: Are you asking how to prove three particular given vectors are othogonal, or are you asking how to construct an orthogonal basis for a space spanned by three given vectors?

Comment: i know that given vectors are orthogonal but i do not know how to prove that for all three at once (between two vectors i can show it). after that i need to construct an orthogonal basis for given vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate $\langle g_i, g_j\rangle$ for all $i,j$ and confirm that $\langle g_i, g_j\rangle = 0$ for $i\neq j$. Then, prove that the $g_i's$ are lienarly independent (i suppose that your vector space has dimension 3). Then, normalize each vector by dividing by its norm.

Comment: between 2 vectors i can prove it, but can i prove for all three at once?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let's begin with 2 vectors first.

2 vectors are orthogonal to eachother if there vectorproduct is 0.